# map array of objects using a dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object

Parsing an array of objects to a new form using a dictionary as alias but i wonder if it can be done without the
Object.keys

```
const mapper = {
    "card_title": "title", 
    "card_content": "content",  
    "card_subtitle": "subtitle" 
}

const data = [
    {
        card_title: "wowo1",
        card_content: "wowo1",
        card_subtitle: "wowo1",
    },
    {
        card_title: "wowo1",
        card_content: "wowo1",
        card_subtitle: "wowo1",
    },
    {
        card_title: "wowo1",
        card_content: "wowo1",
        card_subtitle: "wowo1",
    },
]
```

this is the part where i would like to change it maybe with the spread operator

```
let results = data.map((r) => {
    let obj = {};
    Object.keys(mapper).map(key => 
        obj[mapper[key]] = r[key]
    )
    return obj;
 })
```

`Expected result that i achieved with the code above`

```
[
  { title: 'wowo1', content: 'wowo1', subtitle: 'wowo1' },
  { title: 'wowo1', content: 'wowo1', subtitle: 'wowo1' },
  { title: 'wowo1', content: 'wowo1', subtitle: 'wowo1' }
]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get key, value pairs as an array, and then use  [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to get the new object after mapping the key using `mapper` and keeping value as it is.

Try like below.

```js
const mapper = {
    "card_title": "title", 
    "card_content": "content",  
    "card_subtitle": "subtitle" 
}

const data = [ { card_title: "wowo1", card_content: "wowo1", card_subtitle: "wowo1", }, { card_title: "wowo1", card_content: "wowo1", card_subtitle: "wowo1", }, { card_title: "wowo1", card_content: "wowo1", card_subtitle: "wowo1", }, ]

const output = data.map((item) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => [mapper[key], value])
  )
);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: @lacg95, check this out !!

Answer (score 0):

Without changing `mapper` you will either have to use `Object.keys()` on `mapper` OR on the data objects. Maybe you want to use a `map` ?

```js
const mapper = new Map()
mapper.set('card_title', 'title')
mapper.set('card_content', 'content')
mapper.set('card_subtitle', 'subtitle')


const data = [
    {
        card_title: "wowo1",
        card_content: "wowo1",
        card_subtitle: "wowo1",
    },
    {
        card_title: "wowo1",
        card_content: "wowo1",
        card_subtitle: "wowo1",
    },
    {
        card_title: "wowo1",
        card_content: "wowo1",
        card_subtitle: "wowo1",
    },
]

const mapped = data.map(d => {
    const obj = {}
    mapper.forEach((val, key) => {
        obj[val] = d[key]
    })
    return obj
})


console.log(mapped)
```

##### using `Map` and `reduce()`

```js
const mapper = new Map()
mapper.set('card_title', 'title')
mapper.set('card_content', 'content')
mapper.set('card_subtitle', 'subtitle')


const data = [{
        card_title: "wowo1",
        card_content: "wowo1",
        card_subtitle: "wowo1",
    },
    {
        card_title: "wowo1",
        card_content: "wowo1",
        card_subtitle: "wowo1",
    },
    {
        card_title: "wowo1",
        card_content: "wowo1",
        card_subtitle: "wowo1",
    },
]



const mapped = data.map(src => {
    return Array.from(mapper).reduce((obj, [from, dest]) => {
        obj[dest] = src[from]
        return obj
    }, {})
})

console.log(mapped)
```